# How to extract certain paragraph from text file

Tags: python, extract

```
    def extract_book_info(self):
        books_info = []
        for file in os.listdir(self.book_folder_path):
            title = "None"
            author = "None"
            release_date = "None"
            last_update_date = "None"
            language = "None"
            producer = "None"

            with open(self.book_folder_path + file, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as content:
                book_info = content.readlines()
                for lines in book_info:
                    if lines.startswith('Title'):
                        title = lines.strip().split(': ')
                       
                    elif lines.startswith('Author'):
                        try:
                            author = lines.strip().split(': ')
                           
                        except IndexError:
                            author = 'Empty'
                    elif lines.startswith('Release date'):
                        release_date = lines.strip().split(': ')
                         
                    elif lines.startswith('Last updated'):
                        last_update_date = lines.strip().split(': ')
                       
                    elif lines.startswith('Produce by'):
                        producer = lines.strip().split(': ')
                       
                    elif lines.startswith('Language'):
                        language = lines.strip().split(': ')
                        
                    elif lines.startswith('***'):
                        pass
                        

                books_info.append(Book(title, author, release_date, last_update_date, producer, language, self.book_folder_path))

        with open(self.book_info_path, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as book_file:
            for book_info in books_info:
                book_file.write(book_info.__str__() + "\n")
```

I was using this code tried to extract the book title , author , release_date ,
last_update_date, language, producer, book_path).

This the the output I achieve:

```
['Title', 'The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes'];;;['Author', 'Arthur Conan Doyle'];;;None;;;None;;;None;;;['Language', 'English'];;;data/books_data/;;;
```

This is the output I should achieved.

May I know what method I should used to achieve the following output

```
The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes;;;Arthur Conan Doyle;;;November29,2002;;;May20,2019;;;English;;;
```

This is the example of input:

```
Title: The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes

Author: Arthur Conan Doyle

Release Date: November 29, 2002 [eBook #1661]
[Most recently updated: May 20, 2019]

Language: English

Character set encoding: UTF-8

Produced by: an anonymous Project Gutenberg volunteer and Jose Menendez

*** START OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK THE ADVENTURES OF SHERLOCK HOLMES ***

cover
```

Comment: Hi! Please can you add an example of the input? I supose that each data is in a different line, isn't it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Clearly `book_info.__str__()` is not what you want. Your code is rather messy; perhaps you should not store a list in `book_info`?

Answer (score 0):

`str.split` gives you a list as a result. You're using it to assign to a single value instead.

```py
'Title: Sherlock Holmes'.split(':')  # => ['Title', 'Sherlock Holmes']
```

What I can gather from your requirement you want to access the second element from the `split` every time. You can do so by:

```py
...
for lines in book_info:
    if lines.startswith('Author'):
        _, author = lines.strip().split(':')
    
    elif...
```

Be careful since this can throw an `IndexError` if there is no second element in a `split` result. (That's why there's a `try` on the author param in your code)

Also, avoid calling `__str__` directly. That's what the `str()` function calls for you anyway. Use that instead.